# tailwind error when reading height in react?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to get my head around why tailwind won't generate the height for the item I'm trying to render. Although I've tried a couple of different ways looks like the error is inconsistent and it wont move from a column to another.

Don't think is necessary to post the react bit since the error is definitely not there (or that's what I think)

Screenshots from the devTools attached for reference.

[image: with the error]

[image: without error]

What could it be?

PS: I've also tried different heights but it wont change anything.

I've also tried different heights but it wont change anything.

Comment: Does `h-6` exist in your React code, or are you using dynamic class names? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: I've generated the full class name so it can be that case. Initially, I thought it might be something to do with the class itself but it will apply to all 7 of them which is not the case since there is no issue with the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

bro simply add h-96,h-56 ...... h-numeric values it will work, instead of h-1/6, h-2/3 fractional values